# Google initially ranks new pages for a keyword, but then reverts to ranking our home page

Tags: google-search, wordpress, keywords, pagerank, homepage

I have a WordPress site and every page we build under a specific keyword keeps getting exchanged for the homepage.

We manually add every page to Google Search Console and a couple of minutes later it's there in the Google search results. Hurraaaa

Next day we check and the page has been exchanged for the homepage.

Has anyone had this issue before as I have tried all resources to fix to no avail.

I have changed different sitemaps to see if thats the problem.
I can't optimise the results to each page to get the most benefit from the keyword.

Comment: Do you use that keyword on your home page?

Comment: Are you by chance adding a canonical or redirect from the page back to your homepage?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is eveytime when you add new post, it will be featured in your homepage. So the content will be crawled on both pages. It might get your homepage indexed higher than the orginal post. Try make your homepage with fixed posts. Hope this might help. Thank You!

Comment: This is a good suggestion.  Another way would be to use the `<!--more-->` tag in each article so that only a snippet appears on the home page instead of the whole thing: https://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-properly-use-the-more-tag-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

Your home page is usually the most powerful page on your site. It has more Pagerank than any other page:

- Every page on your site usually links to it
- Many (if not most) external links point to your home page

As such, if the home page uses a keyword on it, it may be very difficult to get another page to rank over it.  The solution is usually to de-optimize the home page for that keyword.   Remove all instances of that keyword from the homepage.    Then even though the Pagerank of the home page is high, the relevance of the home page for that keyword will be low.